# Help with solving for a flow curve:

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

So I'm preparing for a final exam in multivariable and our textbook posed the following question:

find the flow lines of F(x,y) = (-y, x)

Which I can't seem to solve correctly.

We are told that a vector function: $g(t)$ is a flow line if: $g'(t) = F(g(t))$

I thus let: $g(t) = (x(t),y(t))$

and then receive the system of differential equations:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = -y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = x$$

I observe:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = -y \rightarrow -\frac{dx}{dt} = y \rightarrow - \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{dy}{dt} = x  $$

Now I solve the equation:

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} =  -x$$
$$-\frac{1}{x} d^2 x = 1 dt $$
$$-\ln(x) dx = [t + C_1]dt$$
$$x - x\ln(x) = \frac{1}{2}t^2 + C_1t + C_2 $$
$$\ln(\frac{e^x}{x^x}) = \frac{1}{2}t^2 + C_1t + C_2 $$
$$\frac{e^x}{x^x} = e^{\frac{1}{2}t^2 + C_1t + C_2} $$
$$(\frac{e}{x})^x = e^{\frac{1}{2}t^2 + C_1t + C_2} $$

let $u = \frac{x}{e}$
$$(\frac{1}{u})^{eu} = e^{\frac{1}{2}t^2 + C_1t + C_2} $$
$$u^{-u} = e^{\frac{1}{2e}t^2 + C_1t + C_2} $$
$$u^{u} = e^{-\frac{1}{2e}t^2 + C_1t + C_2} $$
$$x = e*(e^{-\frac{1}{2e}t^2 + C_1t + C_2})_{1/2} $$

where $s_{b} = s^{s^{s^{...}}}$ "b times" (tetration)

But the book claims the x component is: $C_1\cos(t) - C_2\sin(t) $

What exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot solve a second-order differential equation by separating variables as you did. You're supposed to know (or have been shown) that the general solution of $\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}+x=0$ is $x(t)=c_1 \cos t + c_2\sin t$.

An alternative solution fitting multivariable calculus is to note that $G(x,y)=(x,y)$ is orthogonal to the flow line at the point $(x,y)$. But $G(x,y)=\frac12\nabla(x^2+y^2)$, and the gradient is normal to level curves. So the flow lines are the level curves $x^2+y^2=c$.

Comment: why is that true? I mean I could prove it now that you have given it but how did you arrive at it?

Comment: Well, one way is to assume a solution of the form $x(t)=e^{kt}$ (this works generally for any constant-coefficient linear differential equation). Substituting, you find $k^2+1=0$, so $k=\pm i$. But $e^{\pm it}=\cos t \pm i\sin t$. More to learn :)

Comment: The equation $x''(t) + x(t) = 0$ is an example of a constant coefficient second order differential equation.  This should be covered by any first course on differential equations.

Comment: Also, most differential equations are solved by guessing what the solution is.  There is no systematic way to solve ODE.  And a first course on ODE should cover the more well known examples of ODEs for which successful guesses have been made.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, what exactly whas the intuition behind using $e^kt$ for your substitution?

Comment: Because exponentials are the functions whose derivatives are constant multiples of the original function. This will make more sense as you study differential equations and linear algebra.

Comment: Can I ask you a follow up question? Is there some way to simplify my fractional tetration into complex exponentials? Like a formula or Identity of some sort?

Comment: I don't know. You might want to post that specifically as a separate question.